# NullPointerException when using putAll(map) to put map into properties

Tags: java, properties, hashmap

I am trying to put a map into a properties using `putAll()` and get a `NullPointerException` even when my map is not null

```
Map<String,Object> map = item.getProperties();
Properties props = new Properties();
if(map!=null) {
    props.putAll(map);  //NPE here
}
```

The `item.getProperties()` returns `Map<String,Object>` and I want to store those properties into a properties file.

I also tried to instantiate the map first

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>()
map = item.getProperties();
Properties props = new Properties();
if(map!=null) {
    props.putAll(map);  //NPE here
}
```

I know that the map is not null, since I can see the map values in the log.

Comment: What is `item.getProperties();` and what does it return?

Comment: it returns Map<String, Object>

Comment: WHen you tried instatiating the map first, you could have avoided the map=item.getProperties() line.. possibly map might have become null again due to this assignment.just debug and see the stuff

Answer (score 6):

The `Properties` class extends `Hashtable` which [does not accept `null` values for its entries.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

> Any non-null object can be used as a key or as a value.

If you try to put a `null` value, the [`Hashtable#put(Object, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put%28K,%20V%29) method throws a `NullPointerException`. It's possible your

```
map = item.getProperties();
```

contains `null` values.

Comment: No, I verified that the map is not null. Also I am checking for !=null before putting into properties

Comment: @NidhishPuthiyadath Not the map, the values inside the map.

Comment: I did print all the values inside the map and they all have key/value pair.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public synchronized V put(K key, V value) {
// Make sure the value is not null
if (value == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}

// Makes sure the key is not already in the hashtable.
Entry tab[] = table;
int hash = key.hashCode();
int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;
for (Entry<K,V> e = tab[index] ; e != null ; e = e.next) {
    if ((e.hash == hash) && e.key.equals(key)) {
    V old = e.value;
    e.value = value;
    return old;
    }
}

modCount++;
if (count >= threshold) {
    // Rehash the table if the threshold is exceeded
    rehash();

        tab = table;
        index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;
}

// Creates the new entry.
Entry<K,V> e = tab[index];
tab[index] = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value, e);
count++;
return null;
}
```

Maybe your map has null key or value.